# Android :iam always getting this prompt can anyone please solve this?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.mcc.wpnews.adapters.MenuCommonAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(MenuCommonAdapter.java:67)
    at com.mcc.wpnews.adapters.MenuCommonAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MenuCommonAdapter.java:47)
    at com.mcc.wpnews.adapters.MenuCommonAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MenuCommonAdapter.java:27)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1306)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:348)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:626)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:693)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1298)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: You are calling `setOnClickListener()` on a `View` that's `null`. There isn't much more to say based on just the log. So, check your `setOnClickListener()` calls. It could be a problem with a `findViewById()` returning `null`. And the [android-studio] tag should only be used for problems with the Android Studio IDE. This isn't an Android Studio problem even though you use Android Studio to write and compile the app. (Theoretically you might as well write and compile with Eclipse, like people did a few years ago. And some still do. But the problem would be the same regardless of the IDE.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to understand what is a NullPointer Exception. Let me explain it as simple as possible.

**Null Pointer Exception :**
This exception is thrown when you call a method or function on a variable (view) that was not yet initialized.

Here, you are getting this error because you might not yet declared and mapped the view to the variable name properly.

**What you have to do ?**
Just check if you have declared the view. Here you are getting error for OnClick Listener. So I assume that it is button. So please check if the button is present in the xml layout and you have properly declared and initialized in your java code.